# Cancel vote when user is deleted

Tags: 7, rating

Is there any way to cancel user votes (if there are any) when I completely delete a user account?

Comment: You can use `hook_user_delete()` (http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.api.php/function/hook_user_delete/7) in your own custom module to delete the vote.  A quick look at the votingapi schema makes me think it would be as simple as deleting from {votingapi_vote} where uid is the user being deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks kiamlaluno for the first guide. I'm really lost about writing even a mini-module.

Here's the code for what i was needing:

```
// Cancel / subtract user vote from 'poll_choice' table, when user account is cancelled.
// The code (db_update) which subtract users vote is a copy from poll.module
function MODULE_NAME_user_delete($account) {
    $uid = $account->uid;
    $votes_id = db_query("SELECT chid FROM {poll_vote} WHERE uid = :account_id", array(':account_id' => $uid))->fetchAll();
    foreach ($votes_id as $vote_id) {
        db_update('poll_choice')
        ->expression('chvotes', 'chvotes - 1')
        ->condition('chid', $vote_id->chid)
        ->execute();
    }
}
```

This is for MODULE_NAME.install. We need it to make sure poll_vote table is not update before this module function is executed.

```
function MODULE_NAME_install(){
  db_update('system')
    ->fields(array('weight' => -1))
    ->condition('name', 'MODULE_NAME', '=')
    ->execute();
}
```